# Optimize the DB select query JSON B type extract

Tags: postgresql, select, postgresql-performance, json

We have a query which we want to optimize for high performance.
The message column in table is of JSONB type and it holds a large json object.
Is there a way to optimze this?
We have an index already on the batch_num

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(message #> '{results}') AS res FROM TABLE WHERE batch_num = '11';
```

Comment: How large is the JSONB, how fast is it now, and how fast does it need to be?

Answer (score 1):

You painted yourself into a corner by modeling this with `jsonb`. The whole large thing has to be read to extract the attribute.

The best I can think of is to break the desired value out of the large object into its own column:

```
ALTER TABLE mytab
   ADD results jsonb GENERATED ALWAYS AS (message -> 'results') STORED;
```

This will work on recent PostgreSQL versions; for older versions you can use a trigger that does the same thing.

Then you only have to read the `results` column instead of the whole `message`.